# Android infinite viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have an app with detail view. This detail view contains some web views(3). Web views are inserted in view pager. I need make this: when I scroll left o right reorder web views in view pager. For example: when I scroll right: actual web view (middle) put into left, right web view (next) put in the middle and to the right web view (next) load next detail. This works for me fine, but I don't know, how can I reinitialize view pager or make something which update view pager ...
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pretty much have a similar question (see [Pattern for using dynamic loaders to load ListView pages in a ViewPager without ListFragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023568/pattern-for-using-loaders-to-load-pages-in-a-viewpager)) and I'm using the same pattern.

I think what you must do is call `yourViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this)` and then in `onPageChanged()` implement the logic in there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to look at [this implementation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CGwQFjAF&url=https://bitbucket.org/ayastrebov/android-infinite-viewpager/src/6db4e945fe66/ViewPager-Sample/src/com/stonerhawk/viewpager/ViewPagerSampleActivity.java&ei=AHbbUO3rE4rbigL8toDoDA&usg=AFQjCNGycr-fuOItQZDjuxK1CySyHnRQlw). I believe you are looking to get a `ViewPager` that say has 3 pages, and when you're on the third page and swipe to the "next" page results in returning to the first page. In this case, I think the implementation found at that link does exactly that. It seems to have a safety net (with the `Bitmap`s) for when fewer than 3 pages are added. It also seems to be able to handle enabling/disabling infinite pagination, though I didn't see a method for setting it dynamically.