# Pattern for using dynamic loaders to load ListView pages in a ViewPager without ListFragments?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-viewpager, android-loadermanager, android-loader

If I have a `ViewPager` with a certain number of pages, what would be the best way of loading the data for each page using the `Loader` framework? Each page contains a ListView with its own adapter instance.

1. Use a separate loader for each page; or
2. Use a single loader that checks which pages are not loaded and loads them

The thing is, it's possible the user may want to quickly swipe through a bunch of pages and thus it should be easy to "cancel" loading pages that aren't needed for performance reasons.

On the other hand it seems like there might be an overhead with having a lot of loaders.

**EDIT:** My `Loader`s actually need to have dynamic IDs to represent the content they are loading. I'm probably going to go with using a mask on the loader ID, and then once the loader is done call `destroyLoader()`.

Comment: What kind of data are you loading?

Comment: I'm just reading data from a local database to populate lists. I guess I want to achieve an effect similar to what Pulse does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a separate `Loader` for each `ListFragment`. Things will get messy very quickly if you try to manage the fragments' `Loader`s from the parent `Activity` (especially if those fragments are being held by a `ViewPager`). `Fragment`s are supposed to be designed for reuse and should not rely on a specific `Activity` in order to function properly. The fact that each `Activity` and each `Fragment` get their own `LoaderManager` instance is further evidence that the Android team didn't want developers to have their `Activity`s loading data for its attached `Fragment`s.

I don't think there will be as much overhead as you are probably expecting there to be... `Loader`s should retain their data across the component's lifecycle and re-query only when the underlying content has changed. It might be a good idea to use a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That would be nice, but unfortunately the ViewPager itself is in a fragment, and fragments cannot be embedded within fragments. The ViewPager is just a regular view pager with views, but I think I'll go with the first method and let you know my results. Also, just edited the question with an important detail.